Keyboard Press Command Not Reaching Gazebo Harmonic
Environment

OS Version: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (noble)
Binary build

Gazebo Harmonic:

gz gui: 8.3.0
gz plugin: 2.0.3
gz sim: 8.6.0

Log
Will be written in the comments
Description

Expected behavior: Successfully moving the robot using keyboard input 
Actual behavior: Keyboard input not detected (by means of checking with gz topic) 

Basically, it's clear that my keyboard press is not detected. There might be something wrong in my setup, but it's not clear yet.
Please help me out. Any help would be very appreciated.
Steps to reproduce

Download this SDF file, and then rename it into building_robot.sdf
Run

gz sim building_robot.sdf -v 4


Click Gazebo GUI, start the simulation, and press arrow up key

Output
GUI screenshoot
No topic published on /cmd_vel
No topic published on /keyboard_keypress
Gazebo topic list
GIF or video of me doing this step by step is on its way.

Log: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1A3pXzFF7D5gBDCRtzMRTrVxtlHg9xr4vOY-7E83NdGY/edit?usp=sharing

Video of me reproducing the issue: https://gifyu.com/image/S18D6

You do not publish "Key publisher" in your sdf file. First you need to open "Key publisher".

Add the code below the frame of the gui tag

<plugin filename="KeyPublisher" name="Key publisher">
        <gz-gui>
          <anchors target="3D View">
            <line own="right" target="right" />
            <line own="top" target="top" />
          </anchors>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">true</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>

full code
 <gui fullscreen="0">
      <plugin filename="GzScene3D" name="3D View">
        <gz-gui>
          <title>3D View</title>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">docked</property>
        </gz-gui>
        <engine>ogre2</engine>
        <scene>scene</scene>
        <ambient_light>0.4 0.4 0.4</ambient_light>
        <background_color>0.8 0.8 0.8</background_color>
        <camera_pose>-6 0 6 0 0.5 0</camera_pose>
        <!-- <horizontal_fov>20,97</horizontal_fov> -->
      </plugin>

      <!-- World control -->
      <plugin filename="WorldControl" name="World control">
        <gz-gui>
          <title>World control</title>
          <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
          <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
          <property type="double" key="height">72</property>
          <property type="double" key="width">150</property>
          <property type="double" key="z">1</property>
          <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
          <anchors target="3D View">
            <line own="left" target="left" />
            <line own="bottom" target="bottom" />
          </anchors>
        </gz-gui>
        <play_pause>true</play_pause>
        <step>true</step>
        <start_paused>true</start_paused>
        <use_event>false</use_event>
        <start_paused>true</start_paused>
        <!-- <service>/world/world_demo/control</service>
        <stats_topic>/world/world_demo/stats</stats_topic> -->
      </plugin>

      <!-- World statistics -->
      <plugin filename="WorldStats" name="World stats">
        <gz-gui>
          <title>World stats</title>
          <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
          <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
          <property type="double" key="height">110</property>
          <property type="double" key="width">290</property>
          <property type="double" key="z">1</property>
          <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
          <anchors target="3D View">
            <line own="right" target="right" />
            <line own="bottom" target="bottom" />
          </anchors>
        </gz-gui>
        <sim_time>false</sim_time>
        <real_time>false</real_time>
        <real_time_factor>true</real_time_factor>
        <iterations>true</iterations>
      </plugin>
      
      <plugin filename="KeyPublisher" name="Key publisher">
        <gz-gui>
          <anchors target="3D View">
            <line own="right" target="right" />
            <line own="top" target="top" />
          </anchors>
          <property key="resizable" type="bool">true</property>
          <property key="width" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="height" type="double">5</property>
          <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
          <property key="showTitleBar" type="bool">false</property>
        </gz-gui>
      </plugin>
    </gui>

OR

Search for the key publisher from the 3 dots in the upper right corner of the simulation and run it


Your code will work, you can get an example from this repository

Hello
Only part of your solution works here (I also don't exactly know why).
When I add the plugin via Gazebo GUI, it works. When I add it programmatically to my SDF file, it doesn't work. When I tried to save the world after adding the plugin and reloading the saved SDF, it doesn't work.
Apparently, the plugin can't be found when the SDF is being loaded.
You can check the updated SDF file here (https://justpaste.it/cgef5) and the error showing that here (https://imgur.com/a/NDKGjjW).

You added the key publisher to the wrong place. You need to open a gui tag and write into the gui tag. I edited the entire code. Add it as I wrote above

Yes, you're absolutely right. Thanks
